# Search for text across multiple m files within the Matlab user interface

Tags: matlab, interface, editor

Is there a way **within** the matlab user interface to search for some text across multiple m-files?

Comment: Given the brevity and simplicity of the answer, I've edited the question to be a bit less wordy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Press Ctrl-Shift-f, or go to menu Edit->Find Files. You will get a nice dialog that hopefully does what you want.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks angainor. I was thrown off the scent by the "Find Files..." label, but in retrospect I probably should have been a bit more persistent before posting the question. Cheers, and +1 to you.