# Edit multiple Matlab .m files using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some 50+ m files that worked in a previous driver version but are outdated for the newer driver version. As a result, I need to find and replace various variable or field names, and sometimes edit variable inputs for all these files.
For example, I'd like to find the line

```
src.aaaa = 100;
```

and replace it to:

```
src.bbbb = 100;
```

another example is to replace:

```
vid = videoinput('xxxx' ,1, 'yyy')
```

with:

```
vid = videoinput('kkkkkk' ,1, 'zzzz')
```

I've searched and found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595662/search-for-text-across-multiple-m-files-within-the-matlab-user-interface), that allows to search in multiple files, but not really edit or replace anything. I can handle matlab so I'm looking for a way to do that in matlab. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the 'Find Files' dialog that you posted (Ctrl-Shift-F) to find each file you are looking for and then 'Find and Replace' (Ctrl+F) the specific lines you want to change.

As an example, find the file with `src.aaaa = 100;` using Ctrl+Shift+F. Then Ctrl+F and add the `src.aaaa = 100;` to the upper textbox and `src.bbbb = 100;` to the lower textbox.

From your post, it is unclear as to whether or not this would be feasible since I do not know how many different lines you would like to change in these m-files. How many are there? Are the m-files similar or are they all different?

If there are specific variables you are searching for, you could write a script to loop search through all the m-files using the `dir` function. Read the m-file into a string variable using `fscanf`. Then replace the variable in the string using `strrep`. And finally using `fprintf` to write to a new .m file with the corrected variables.

**Refer to:**

- http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

Comment: thanks, but that's not realistic if I have more than 50 files with more than 10 items to edit in each file (or it'd take me a good hour). All the m files are part of a big program that uses this camera driver, so some might contain some lines to be replaced some wont. If I could do the Ctrl+F trick for all the files at once it'd be great, but opening 50+ files and edit 10+ items that's 500+ itereations

Answer (score 2):

A bit outside the box - but I would use the [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) command - it does exactly what you want and is quick on it, but is you need to call it with `system` and build the command string. If you are on windows you may need to install it through [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Answer (score 1):

The m-File implementing Sekkou's suggestion:

```
clear all;
clc;


%% Parameter

directory           = 'd:\xxx';
oldString           = 'the old text';
newString           = 'the new text';
regularExpression   = '[\w]+\.m';


%% Determine files to manipulate

cd(directory)

allFilesInDirectory = dir;


%% Manipulieren der verweneten Dateien

disp('Manipulated Files:');

for idx = 1 : length(allFilesInDirectory)

    if (~isempty ( regexp(allFilesInDirectory(idx).name, '[\w]+\.m','match') ))

        disp(allFilesInDirectory(idx).name);

        % Read and manipulate Text
        fileIdRead  = fopen(allFilesInDirectory(idx).name, 'r');
        fileText    = fscanf(fileIdRead,'%c');

        fileTextNew = strrep(fileText, oldString, newString);

        fclose(fileIdRead);


        % Write Text
        fileIdWrite = fopen(allFilesInDirectory(idx).name, 'w');

        fprintf(fileIdWrite, '%c', fileTextNew);

        fclose(fileIdWrite);
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ergodicity replied with some great code, but:

- Some comments are in German rather than English
- There is a general lack in commenting, which makes it hard to understand

I have attempted to fix these problems with the code below (I can't seem to get the code to display in MATLAB format very well using "language: lang-matlab", so paste it into MATLAB for easier reading):

```matlab
close all;
clear all;
clc;
%% Parameters
% The directory in which to replace files. Currently this code does not modify files in
% sub-directories
directory           = 'C:\Users\Name\Wonderful code folder';
% The string that will be replaced
oldString           = sprintf('terrible mistake');
% The replacement string
newString           = sprintf('all fixed now');
% The file name condition - what type of files will be examined
% It must contain any of the English character set (letters, numbers or underscore
% character i.e. a-zA-Z_0-9) and ends with a ".m" MATLAB extension (use \.txt for text files)
regularExpression   = '[\w]+\.m';

%% Determine files to update, and update them as necessary
% Change the current directory to the user-specified one
cd(directory)
% Put the details of all files and folders in that current directory into a structure
allFilesInDirectory = dir;
% Initialise indexes for files that do and do not contain oldString
filesWithStringIndex = 1;
filesWithoutStringIndex = 1;
% For the number of files and folders in the directory
for idx = 1 : length(allFilesInDirectory)

    % If the file name contains any of the English character set (letters, numbers or
    % underscore character i.e. a-zA-Z_0-9) and ends with a ".m" filetype...
    if (~isempty ( regexp(allFilesInDirectory(idx).name, '[\w]+\.m','match') ))

        % Open the file for reading
        fileIdRead  = fopen(allFilesInDirectory(idx).name, 'r');

        % Extract the text
        fileText = fscanf(fileIdRead,'%c');

        % Close the file
        fclose(fileIdRead);

        % Search for occurrences of oldString
        occurrences = strfind(fileText,oldString);

        % If an occurrence is found...
        if ~isempty(occurrences)

            % Replace any occurrences of oldString with newString
            fileTextNew = strrep(fileText, oldString, newString);

            % Open the file for writing
            fileIdWrite = fopen(allFilesInDirectory(idx).name, 'w');

            % Write the modified text
            fprintf(fileIdWrite, '%c', fileTextNew);

            % Close the file
            fclose(fileIdWrite);

            % Update the list of files that contained oldString
            filesWithString{filesWithStringIndex} = allFilesInDirectory(idx).name;

            % Update the index for files that contained oldString
            filesWithStringIndex = filesWithStringIndex + 1;

        else
            % Update the list of files that did not contain oldString
            filesWithoutString{filesWithoutStringIndex} = allFilesInDirectory(idx).name;

            % Update the index for files that did not contain oldString
            filesWithoutStringIndex = filesWithoutStringIndex + 1;

        end
    end
end
%% Display what files were changed, and what were not
% If the variable filesWithString exists in the workspace
if exist('filesWithString','var')
    disp('Files that contained the target string that were updated:');
    % Display their names
    for i = 1:filesWithStringIndex-1, disp(filesWithString{i}); end
else
    disp('No files contained the target string');
end
% Insert a clear line between lists
disp(' ');
% If the variable fileWithoutString exists in the workspace
if exist('filesWithoutString','var')
    disp('Files that were not updated:');
    % Display their names
    for j = 1:filesWithoutStringIndex-1, disp(filesWithoutString{j}); end
else
    disp('All files contained the target string.');
end
```